# dns domain not pointing correctly

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

i have purchased a domain concretex.com from name.com.

The domain is actually hosted on my server with ip 108.174.53.215. Also the DNS(Bind) is hosted on this ip.
now i want to manage this domain's dns from my own bind dns server.
I have installed virtualmin.
i have inserted the name server ns1.name.com and ns2.name.com as nameservers. but i am unable to get the dns resolve concretex.com.
Here is screenshot of virtualmin dns records.
http://i40.tinypic.com/1goufn.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to tell the registrar / company you bought your domain from [name.com?] that 108.174.53.215 is an authoritative source of information for concretex.com.

and.. in most cases you'll need to have at least two dns servers, not just one. you can use free dns like [this one](http://xname.org/) to be your secondary dns.

usually you'll have to have to provide host names [rather than ip address] together with ip addreses for your name servers.at name.com you'll delegate concretex.com to the following address:

- ns1.concretex.com / 108.174.53.215
- ns0.xname.org [ or ns1 or ns2 - check [this](https://www.xname.org/faq.php?language=en#item4) ]

on your own server 108.174.53.215 you'll have to create basic dns record for concretex.com zone - something that will contain at least:

```
@ IN NS ns1.concretex.com. ; yes it's a dot at the end and it's correct
@ IN NS ns0.xname.org.
ns1 IN A 108.174.53.215
www IN A 1.2.3.4
; and probably more
```

you'll have to configure your bind to allow zone transfer to the name servers of xname.org [ you'll find the list of their source ips [here](https://www.xname.org/faq.php?language=en#item4) ]. to prevent abuse:

- [dont allow zone transfers](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-restrict-unauthorized-zone-transfers-dns-bind.html) from other ip addreses and only to them.
- [dont allow recursive dns queries](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch-sec-services.en.html#s-configure-bind) except of those coming from your local network and loopback.
- chrooting bind is always a good idea; it's a bit distribution-dependent, just [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=bind%20chroot%20tutorial).

Answer (score 3):

It's really unclear from your description where the problem is.
So here's the general steps you'd go through.

1. Buy domain from registrar.
2. Get hosting for DNS.

   - If you're self-hosting DNS, setup Glue records with Registrar.
   - Point Nameserver records to DNS Host for Domain with Registrar.
3. Get web site hosting.

   - If self-hosting, through VPS or whatever, you can skip this step.
4. At DNS Host create records for website.

   - Specifically you'll want `A` records for `www` and `@` (@ = default record) that point to the IP of your webhost.
5. If you want e-mail setup for the site you'll need to configure DNS for that too. Since you didn't mention it, I'm not filling this one out, it's a lot more steps.